# Where to find a propriety driver for ATI X1150 on Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon, ubuntu-9.10

I have a Dell Vostro 1000 laptop, with Ubuntu 9.10 AMD64 installed.

Everything was perfect except the hell ATI driver.  Everytime I tried a standby or hibernate with default shipped X.org driver, then my computer would hang at the next resuming.

I followed a guy by downgrading my drivers so that I can standby, hibernate, but the problem will occasionally occurs (which harm me really much).  So, I decided to get a propriety driver from AMD, but I failed. Everything from AMD (ATI) was poorly documented, poorly supported.

I checked Google but I didn't find anything. There's some guide on how to working around for Ubuntu Gutsy or Jaunty but no working around yet for 9.10.

I'm so frustrated.  I don't need any fancy 3D. I just need a screen of appropriate resolution that allow me to suspend and hibernate and then resume properly.

Where can I find a working driver?  How do I install it?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think there is a driver from ati for that card on karmic. maybe you can try the 2.6.33 kernel with xorg-edgers ppa?

Comment: Yepp. You need a bleeding edge system with the latest xorg, kernel and ati drivers. Use the xorg-edgers and install the very latest kernel by hand or grab it from an other PPA. || If you want 3D and prop, use Debian 5.0.

Comment: Good news, I will give the latest kernel and latest xorg a try.